# Odoo: How to process winmail.dat attached in conversations?

Tags: python, odoo, tnef, winmail.dat

We have some customers who uses Microsoft Outlook to send attachments. However in odoo we see only `winmail.dat` files (while everything looks ok in mail client).

Is there any way to force odoo to expose `winmail.dat` content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Microsoft Outlook uses [Transport Neutral Encapsulation Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Neutral_Encapsulation_Format) and packs all attachments in one file.

There is a good python parser for tnef format - [`tnefparse`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tnefparse). I'd suggest you to use it and write simple module to extend `mail.thread` model like this

```py
from tnefparse import TNEF
from openerp.osv import osv

class MailThread(osv.Model):
    _inherit = 'mail.thread'

    def _message_extract_payload(self, message, save_original=False):
        body, attachments = \
            super(MailThread, self)\
                ._message_extract_payload(message, save_original=save_original)

        new_attachments = []
        for name, content in attachments:
            new_attachments.append((name, content))
            if name and name.strip().lower() in ['winmail.dat', 'win.dat']:
                try:
                    winmail = TNEF(content)
                    for attach in winmail.attachments:
                        new_attachments.append((attach.name, attach.data))
                except:
                    # some processing here
                    pass

        return body, new_attachments
```

You can find more information on how to do custom modules [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html).

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try

Comment: by the way, a new tnefparse 1.3.0 version has just been released with a lot of fixes and improvements.

Comment: thefparse is a very handy tool/library which takes care of processing winmail.dat